# What is the correct punctuation to use in this case?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, semicolons, colons

If I have a sentence like:

> The royal family is extremely rich: The sled that pulls the princess
>   is shaped like a golden swan, the celebrations last 3 days, and the
>   bride and groom walk under a canopy made of purple velvet embroidered
>   with pearls.

Is a colon the proper punctuation to use after *rich*, or would a semicolon be more suitable? Why?

Comment: As a Brit, I'd take issue with capitalising "the" after the colon. But I wouldn't use a colon anyway - a full stop would suit better imho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although both are independent clauses, a colon is the more appropriate choice here because a compound list follows the initial proclamation and serves to support its assertion.