# How to make a statement and then iterate through a list thereafter

Tags: grammar, sentence

I would like to state a fact, and then, if possible, in the same sentence, iterate over a list of properties related to that fact.

Here are a few examples:

> The construction site had two entrances: one to the east, and one to the west.
>
> or
>
> The construction site had two entrances, one to the east; and one to the west.

Is either of these the preferred method?  Are there ways of saying this in a similar fashion that would be correct or 'more preferable'?

EDIT: I've recently found this >
http://theoatmeal.com/comics/semicolon < which suggests the semicolon method is the right way to go.  I'll leave the question here to invoke any comments.

Comment: Your link does also say "don't use it with conjunctions". You're using "and", so the semicolon is wrong according to your link (als also according to my sense of languages, but that's another thing)

Comment: See this similar question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73896/what-is-the-correct-punctuation-to-use-in-this-case/

Comment: @cornbreadninja Thanks! Does your answer still apply given that the items I am appending aren't really in 'support' of my original statement?

Comment: Forget I said that.  @Em1 is right because *one to the east and one to the west* doesn't stand as an independent clause.

Comment: I frame the sentences in these ways in writing:

(1)The construction site has two entrances, one to the east and the other to the west.


(2)The construction site has three entrances: first/one to the east, second to the west and third to the south.


(3)The construction site has an entrance each to the east, the west, the south and the north. (Not really a good choice though)


(4)The construction site has two entrances, both to the east.


(5)The construction site has three entrances,  one towards east and the other two towards west.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr (3) is definitely not going to help.  It leaves an open end as to wether or not there are more entrances.  I need to explicitly state that there were only two entrances.  Thanks!

Comment: @Geoist: I said that choice (3) is not a good fit, see above. Something like "the only entrances to the construction site are towards the east and towards the west" should be sufficient.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr I saw that, was just agreeing with you and confirming the fact. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first example looks quite nice:

> The construction site had two entrances: One to the east and one to the west.

I, personally, prefer capitalizing the letter after the colon, though British people tend to use lower case.

Your second example is wrong. You can use the semicolon to connect two sentences but *one to the west* is actually not a full sentence. Moreover you use the conjunction *and* to connect the two parts and then you only can place a comma precedent to *and* but not a semicolon.

Comment: Are there any definitive sources you can point me to that can confirm this?  Google just returns people's random blog articles which aren't really reliable. (I don't mean to pry.) Thx

Comment: @Geoist What exactly is doubtful? The link you provided do confirm most of my points.

Comment: The link I provided _may_ confirm your points, but the link also provides an example where the semi colon is used to separate items in a list as exemplified by my second sentence.  In the link, see the part under the hamburger where the guy is eating a jar of mayonnaise.  Due to this discrepancy, I'd hardly consider my provided link to be an authority and still feel reluctant about either method.

Comment: @Geoist: I'm not a definitive source, but I can tell you rather confidently that Em's answer is a good one.  If you want more authority, try checking out the [OWL](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/566/1/). As for the semi-colon, I've got three words of advice: no, no, and no!  Here's a good "semi-colon test": change the semi-colon to a period; the result should be grammatically correct.  In this case: "The construction site had two entrances, one to the east.  And one to the west." Goodness, no...

Comment: @Em1 Further confirmation of the semicolon method is here: http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/semicolons_in_lists.htm

Comment: @Geoist: As for the "mayo guy", that's a different condition altogether. You use **commas** to separate items in a list, right? (_My three favorite actors are Morgan Freeman, Tom Hanks, and Clint Eastwood._) But when the list items are more complex, and contain commas themselves, then you use **semi-colons** instead. (_My three favorite movies are_ The Man from Snowy River, _which is set in Australia;_ Big Fish, _which is about a man's estranged relationship with his father; and_ The Good, the Bad and the Ugly, _which, besides being a classic spaghetti western, has a great musical score._)

Comment: @J.R. Thanks, with the "mayo guy", I missed the critical bit about the pre-existing commas.  [OWL](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/566/1/) Confirms this in the third paragraph under semicolon.  So if my original requirement was "The site had three entrances, one to the east for women, children, and the elderly; one to the north for royalty, police and dignitaries; and one to the south for common people." I would be correct.

Comment: @Geoist: Yes, correct. P.S. The Grammar Monster link you provided confirms this as well, under the **Hot Tip** in the box to the right.

Answer (score 1):

For these examples, several correct punctuations are possible besides the correct one shown in your first example.  In the second one, the comma and semicolon combination is wrong.  It would still be wrong if *one to the east*  were replaced by an independent clause, as then you'd have a runon sentence.  It's less clear-cut when *one to the west* is replaced; for example, *It had two entrances, one of them to the east; and that's where I went in* is sound.

As noted, the first example is correct, but it's portentous (ie puffed up).  Instead of *The construction site had two entrances: one to the east, and one to the west* I'd write *The construction site had entrances east and west* or perhaps *The construction site had east and west entrances*, and let people assume no other entrances exist.  But if it's important to emphasize the existence of no other entrances, there might be nothing much shorter than what you have.  For example, I think neither of *The construction site had two entrances, east and west* and *The construction site had two entrances, both east and west* perfectly distinguishes between there being one east entrance and one west entrance *vs* two east entrances and two west entrances. *The construction site had just an east and a west entrance* might work, or more explicitly, *The construction site had just one east and one west entrance*.

Comment: Thanks, you spotted the key issue where I need to _emphasise the existence of no other entrances_.  I didn't pick up on the possibility that the number of entrances could be implied, good point.  I don't know why I'm being so pedantic about this one sentence.